# PROGRAM_ERROR raised by controlled types, hard to pinpoint where it's raised exactly in my code?

Tags: ada

I use John English: [Ada95: The Craft of Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/craft/html/contents.htm) as a tutorial, and I'm currently at the expression calculator chapter. Which means writing an arithmetical expression calculator with object oriented methods.
The program compiles but raised:

```
mehdi@debian ~/expressions> ./driver
Execution terminated by unhandled exception
raised PROGRAM_ERROR : expressions.adb:4 finalize/adjust raised exception
Call stack traceback locations:
0x408749 0x408aa4 0x401af6 0x4024ee 0x7f05fe7132df 0x401988 0xfffffffffffffffe
```

and from those funny numbers I could only extract that information:

```
addr2line --exe=driver 0x408749 0x408aa4 0x401af6 0x4024ee 0x7f690a2b32df 0x401988 0xfffffffffffffffe
/home/mehdi/expressions/pointers.adb:40 (discriminator 6)
/home/mehdi/expressions/expressions.adb:17
/home/mehdi/expressions/driver.adb:8
/home/mehdi/expressions/b__driver.adb:267
??:0
??:?
??:0
```

The aforementioned lines, one after the other:

```
   overriding procedure Adjust (Object: in out Smart_Pointers) is
   begin
       Object.Node.Count := Object.Node.Count + 1;
   end Adjust; -- here FIRST ONE
   end Evaluate; -- SECOND
   Put_Line("Le résultat de 598-8/84+25*5*(-5/54) est " & EVALUATE(Expression, Expression_string)'Img); -- THIRD
   Ada_Main_Program; -- FOURTH
```

I still have no clue, except that it's related to controlled types.
The only controlled thingy I put, I listed it here.
Oh, there's also FINALIZE:

```
 overriding procedure Finalize (Object: in out Smart_Pointers) is
      procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(Accessor_type, Accessor_access);
   begin
      Object.Node.Count := Object.node.Count - 1;
      if Object.Node.Count = 0 then Free(Object.Node);
      end if;
   end;
```

But it doesn't seem to matter.

I'm a beginner, so I don't how to use gdb or GPS's debugger facilities yet.
If anyone has an idea, or need a bigger piece of code, make yourself known ;-)

Comment: `don't [know] how to use [a debugger] yet. If anyone has an idea` learn how to make most of your tools and your time. Learn how to use a/your debugger. If you still can't handle a particular problem, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Really we need to see more complete code, specifically an [MCVE], including declarations. I never use a debugger in Ada, the  exception messages are generally spookily close to the actual mistake, saving a hell of a lot of dev time over certain other languages. In this case my first guess is `constraint_error` incrementing Node.Count, converted to Program_Error by the controlled type. So Egil's made the best guess in the absence of information.

Comment: `overriding procedure Adjust (Object: in out Smart_Pointers) is` for sake of accuracy : this is not Ada95 stuff. `overriding` keyword appeared after Ada95 release (i would say Ada 2005). And as mentionend and upvoted : learn gdb in gnatpro studio, it is incredibly useful to be fluent with gdb commands (simple google search will help you find your way)

Answer (score 6):

It is a bounded error for `Adjust` or `Finalize` to raise exceptions. If that happens, the runtime will raise a `PROGRAM_ERROR`. In your `Adjust`, there's two possibilities of an exception being raised:

1. `Object.Node` is `null`
2. `Object.Node.Count` could be incremented outside the bounds of its type

If you don't want to use a debugger, you could add an exception handler to `Adjust` and `Finalize`.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `Adjust` has to cope with copying an empty smart pointer.

I don’t see it in the ARM, but `Finalize` can be called more than once on the same object, so you have to cater for that.

[My smart pointer code](https://sourceforge.net/p/booch95/code/ci/default/tree/src/bc-support-smart_pointers.adb#l52) has

```ada
--  Finalize may be called more than once on the same object.
--
--  The first time its called, we may set Tmp to a non-null value
--  which designates the actual shared object and then proceed to
--  decrement the count and, if no references remain, delete the
--  used memory. But, in any case, *this* smart pointer no longer
--  references the actual object, so another call to Finalize will
--  have no effect.
procedure Finalize (Obj : in out Pointer) is
   Tmp : Ref := Obj.Rep;
begin
   Obj.Rep := null;
   if Tmp /= null then
      Tmp.Count := Tmp.Count - 1;
      if Tmp.Count = 0 then
         Delete (Tmp.Value);
         Delete (Tmp);
      end if;
   end if;
end Finalize;
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607664/230513), it was `Object.Node is null`.

Comment: It seems controlled types can be a lot more complicated or said otherwise, hardly predictable than presented in grassroots level Ada books. No wonder this feature is disabled in Spark. I'll think about it twice next time. Ps: I did remember reading in the RM that Finalize can be called more than one on the same object, but I couldn't find IN WHICH CASES exactly.